# How paper-tag survive in the dry-cleaning process?

Tags: materials, solvents, cleaning

This prevent the clothes from being ruined by **ink** on the paper tag.

To put the garments attached with this paper through the whole process of dry-cleaning,

I have the questions listed below

1. paper type?
2. ink type?
3. Is paper need to be coated?
4. if need >> what is this coating technique called?
5. printing technique (refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printing)

Note that, the **dry-cleaning solvent** is not just water.

---

Does that sound scientific?

I don't know the more appropriate place to ask this kind of question. If there is, just let me know.

Thanks, 
pakorn

Comment: By the way, welcome to chemistry.SE! You have taken the tour, so I assume you know what this is about.

Comment: Thanks MARamezani. I think, this question is some kind of technology/chemistry-related. I was looking for the tech SE and you can guess what I found. no tech!
SE does it the narrower way to categorize the sites. Narrow enough to make me not to know where I am supposed to post this. Or I should tell SE in the area51.

Comment: This Q is enough chemistry for a good answerer to answer it right here. No need to panic! :)